# Trouble formatting string from DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, string, datatable

I'm saving a numeric value into a datatable cell (no datatype for the cell has been explicitly declared), then later retrieving that data and trying to format it into a string.  Problem is that nothing I've tried will properly format the string.

> 50000 --> 50,000

I've tried (where r is the row in a loop):

```
String.Format("{0:0,0}", r["columnName"])

r["columnName"].ToString("n0")
```

And several variations without any luck.  Most of the time I just get the number without the comma.

Comment: What does String.Format("{0:0,0}",int.Parse(r["columnName"].ToString())) give you?

Comment: @soandos -It gives me what I need.  Thanks.  Make that an answer and you'll get the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.Format("{0:0,0}",int.Parse(r["columnName"].ToString()))

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to have more context for what you're trying to do, but here is an example of getting a value out of a DataTable and then formatting it as desired.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add( "cellName", typeof( double ) );
dt.Rows.Add( 123.45 );
string val = ( (double)dt.Rows[0]["cellName"] ).ToString( "N" ); // val = "123.45"
```

I'm explicitly casting the value back to a double before calling ToString.  You could also call string.Format on that value instead of ToString and it should work just as well.

EDIT: If you're storing the value as a string and then want to format it, use this:

```
string val = ( double.Parse( dt.Rows[0]["cellName"] ) ).ToString( "N" );
```

This does assume that the value is parsable though (i.e. isn't null).

Comment: I think he's able to get the string, he just wants to format it so that a value 1000 is displayed as 1,000.

Comment: So you're storing the value as a string, but then want to format the string properly?  If that's the case, instead of casting dt.Rows[0]["cellName"] to a double, parse it.  I'll edit the answer to show this.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm storing the value as.  What is the default datatype for a DataTable cell if none is specified?

Comment: string is the default if you don't specify a type.  At any rate, since you have a numeric value, if you parse it into an int, double, etc. before trying to format it it will work ok.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but you could just iterate backwards from the tail-end of the string (or from the decimal point) adding a comma every three characters until you run out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with these methods is that depending on the structure of the underlying table that field may be null. If you try to cast a null value held as an object (in the DataTable) to string,integer, decimal, or what have you... your app will blow up 100% of the time. Unless your DataSet is a strongly typed data set you will always want to do this error checking.  As a matter of fact, writing a small data reading class to read string, decimals, date times, integers, whatever... is a must in any Data access operations having to do with Database....

So here is more error proof approach which idealy should be wrapped in a helper method as shown here:

```
public static string GetFormatedDecimalString(DataRow row, string columnName, string format)
{

    string ColumnNameStringValue = String.Empty;
    decimal ColumnNameValue = Decimal.Zero;

    if( row[columnName) == DBNull.Value )
    {
        ColumnNameValue = Decimal.Zero;
    }
    else
    {
        ColumnNameStringValue = row[columnName].ToString();

        if( ! Decimal.TryParse(ColumnNameStringValue, out ColumnNameValue )
        {
           ColumnNameValue = Decimal.Zero;
        }

        // if the if statement evaluated to false the ColumnNameValue will have the right
        // number you are looking for.
    }

    return ColumnNameValue.ToString(format);
}
```

passing "N" or "{0:0,0}" as the format string will work just fine.